# ¿Porque combobox solo selecciona el valor por defecto, e ignora el item seleccionado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

el problema en especifico es que al momento de ejecutar el código, y seleccionar los items de los combobox, el resultado del area que muestra el codigo es de los valores por defecto, no de los seleccionados.Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Gracias

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



ven=Tk()
ven.geometry("1600x900+1+0")
ven.title("ENVOLVENTE OPERATIVA DE COMPLETAMIENTO")

top=Frame(ven,width=1600,height=50,relief="raise",bg="powder blue",bd=10)
top.pack(side=TOP)

F1=Frame(ven,width=800,height=500,relief="raise",bd=10)
F1.pack(side=LEFT)

F2=Frame(ven,width=700,height=700,relief="raise",bd=10)
F2.pack(side=RIGHT)

titulo=Label(top,font=('arial',50,'bold'),text="ENVOLVENTE OPERATIVA ",fg="black",bd=10,anchor='w')
titulo.grid(row=0,column=0)
    


#Datos de entrada

Odlbl=Label(F1,font=('arial',10,'bold'),text="Diametro externo (in) ",fg="red",bd=16,anchor='w')
Odlbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
od=ttk.Combobox(F1,textvariable=DoubleVar,font=('arial',10,'bold'),width=25)
od['value']=('2.375','2.875','3.5','4','4.5','5.5','6.5')
od.current(0)
od.grid(row=0,column=1)
od=float(od.get())


Idlbl=Label(F1,font=('arial',10,'bold'),text="Diametro interno (in) ",fg="red",bd=16,anchor='w')
Idlbl.grid(row=1,column=0)
id=ttk.Combobox(F1,textvariable=DoubleVar,font=('arial',10,'bold'),width=25)
id['value']=('1.992','1.995','2.041','2.259','2.441','2.992','4','4.09','4.184')
id.current(0)
id.grid(row=1,column=1)
id=float(id.get())

area = (((od) **(2)) - ((id) ** (2))) * 0.7854
print(area)
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, el problema en especifico es que al momento de ejecutar el código, y seleccionar los items de los combobox, el resultado del area que muestra el codigo es de los valores por defecto, no de los seleccionados.Agradezco cualquier ayuda.Gracias

Comment: Solo calculas el área una vez, necesitas o bién un botón que al pulsarlo recalcule el área con el contenido actual de los comboboxs o que cada vez que se seleccione un item en alguno de los combobox recalcule el área llamando a una función.

Answer (score 3):

Como te comenté solo calculas una vez el área nada más ejecutar el código. Para que recalcule el área cuando se seleccionen los items debes asociar una señal a un evento.

No aclaras muy bién que es lo que pretendes hacer, podrias crear un botón de forma que cuando el usuario seleccione los valores oportunos lo pulse y se calcule el área. Otra opción es que cuando se cambie alguno o los dos valores de los ComboBox automáticamente se recalcule el área sin necesidad de usar nada más.

Siguiendo esta última idea solo tenemos que crear una función (`calcular_area`) que será llamada cada vez que se seleccione un item en alguno de los comboboxs:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def calcular_area(*event):
    area = (float(od_cbox.get()) ** 2 - float(id_cbox.get()) ** 2) * 0.7854
    print(area)

ven = tk.Tk()
ven.geometry("1600x900+1+0")
ven.title("ENVOLVENTE OPERATIVA DE COMPLETAMIENTO")

top = tk.Frame(ven, width=1600, height=50, relief="raise", bg="powder blue", bd=10)
top.pack(side=tk.TOP)

f1 = tk.Frame(ven, width=800, height=500, relief="raise", bd=10)
f1.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

f2 = tk.Frame(ven, width=700, height=700, relief="raise", bd=10)
f2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

titulo = tk.Label(top, font=('arial', 50, 'bold'), text="ENVOLVENTE OPERATIVA ", fg="black", bd=10, anchor='w')
titulo.grid(row=0, column=0)



#Datos de entrada

od_lbl = tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Diametro externo (in) ",fg="red", bd=16, anchor='w')
od_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
od_cbox = ttk.Combobox(f1, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), width=25)
od_cbox['value'] = ('2.375', '2.875', '3.5', '4', '4.5', '5.5', '6.5')
od_cbox.current(0)
od_cbox.grid(row=0, column=1)
od_cbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", calcular_area)


id_lbl = tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Diametro interno (in) ", fg="red", bd=16, anchor='w')
id_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
id_cbox = ttk.Combobox(f1, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar, font=('arial',10,'bold'), width=25)
id_cbox['value'] = ('1.992', '1.995', '2.041', '2.259', '2.441', '2.992', '4', '4.09', '4.184')
id_cbox.current(0)
id_cbox.grid(row=1, column=1)
id_cbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", calcular_area)

calcular_area() # Llamamos a la función si queremos que calcule el area con los valores por defecto al iniciar la GUI.
```

Ahora cada vez que se seleccione un item en alguno de los comboboxs se recalcula e imprime el area.

He modificado algunas cosas, lo más importante es:

- Es una mala práctica, además de peligroso, realizar un import de la forma `from módulo import *`. He modificado el código usando `import tkinter as tk` que si es una forma correcta de importar, además de hacer el código mucho más legible.
- Usas una variable con el nombre 'id', `id` es una palabra reservada en Python y debes evitar sobreescribirla ya que puedes ocasionar errores si algún módulo de los que usas llegara a usarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta, voy a tomar nota de tus consejos@FJSevilla

Comment: @MIGUELTORO si te respondió la pregunta, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada con el tick (el chulito, pues) que está a la izquierda de la respuesta, junto a los votos